# Random number for variable when called

Tags: python-3.x, random

I'm fairly new in programming and python in general. I already learned `for`, `if`'s, and `while`, and I'm trying to make a pretty decent rpg/dungeon game. I'm wondering how do I make a variable have a random number when used for the "damage".

I used randint(a, b) for the variable but it is only random once.

This is a creature example:

```py
name_slime = "Red Slime"
slime_hp = randint(100, 200)
slime_atk = randint(1, 2)
slime_crit = 60
slime_evade = 10
slime_exp = randint(1, 5)
slime_chance = randint(50, 60)
```

And these will get called on another function:

```py
def battle(enemy_name, enemy_hp, enemy_atk, enemy_crit, enemy_evade, enemy_exp):# Battle sequence

    while enemy_hp > 0:
        global player_hp, potion_count

        print(f"{enemy_name}'s Stats:")
        print(f"HP: {enemy_hp}  Power: {enemy_atk}  Crit Chance: {enemy_crit}%  Evade: {enemy_evade}%\n")
        print("Your Stats:")
        ....

        print("Action:\n1. Attack\n2. Parry\n3. Use Potion")
        choice = input("> ")


        if choice == "1":
            ....

        elif choice == "2":
            ....

        elif choice == "3":
            ....


    print(f"You gained {enemy_exp} EXP")
    exp_check(enemy_exp)
    print(f"Your EXP is now {player_exp}/{exp_limit}")
```

P.S: I scraped a lot of things in this code because it's quite long for there is a lot of lines for the calculation.

Here's the full code if anyone can help:
https://pastebin.com/iFMZyY4z

I'll just take the exp for this case. 
In the variable "slime_exp" it should give a number between 1 and 5. But when i tried fighting the creature multiple times in one run (not exiting the terminal) it always give the same amount of exp each time.

I'm thinking that the `randint(1, 5)` is defined when the script is run and not when the variable is used.

This happens for all variable that have `randint()`
How can I make it so that it will be random when the variable is used?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `choice` method is an alternative that might be suitable for you:

```py
slime_exp = range(1,6) # slime_exp is now a variable of 'range' type!
```

For more infomation about the `range()` function see [range in Python](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=range+python&t=h_&ia=web).

And whenever you use the variable `slime_exp` you can use `choice(slime_exp)`.

`choice` is a function that returns a pseudo-random value from a `list`, `range`, `tuple`, `string`. For more information see [choice in Python](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=choice+python&t=h_&ia=web). 
Note that, to use choice you have to "import" it first by doing one of these options:

- `from random import *` (not very advised)
- `import random` (in this case you should use `random. choice` instead of just `choice`)
- or `from random import choice`

And when you want to use the variable `slime_exp`, you just use `choice(slime_exp)` instead of `slime_exp`. Note that this may be a good option if you don't need to use the same value several times since the exact value of `choice(slime_exp)` is "pseudo-randomized" everytime you use it.

Comment: i did ```from random import choice``` and did ```choice(slime_exp)``` and it gave me this error ```TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()```. Also, should i put it inside ```battle(parameter)``` ? because the number will get used again for "HP: {enemy_hp} ..."

Comment: Do this: `slime_exp = range(1,6) # range(1,6) == (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

Comment: `slime_exp` should be a `tuple` or a `list` so that `choice()` works.

Comment: should i do ```battle(... choice(slime_exp) ...``` ?

Comment: Yes, you should do that. Note that `choice(slime_exp)` returns an `int`, in my answer.

Comment: ok, it works but now it said ```TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'range' and 'int'``` on line ```while enemy_hp > 0:``` I replace all the ```randint()``` with ```range()```

Comment: Instead of `enemy_hp`, write `choice(enemy_hp)`.

Comment: You can not replace all `randint`'s with `range`'s just like that, you need to add 1 to the second argument. Eg.: `print(randint(1,3))`prints a pseudo-random number, `1`, `2` or `3`; while `print(choice(range(1,3)))` prints a pseudo-random number, `1` or `2`. The second argument is not included. [range in Python](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=range+python&t=hp&ia=web)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to update the `slime_exp` variable and call it when needed, like below.

```
slime_exp = randint(1, 5)

def update_slime_exp():
    global slime_exp
    slime_exp = randint(1, 5)

update_slime_exp()
print(slime_exp)
```

However, changing the state of global variable is not a good programming practise. Instead get the random number as return value and use it when needed instead of storing it in a global variable.